# How to change browser page title dynamically to match it with <h1> title in javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-title

I would like to change my page title dynamically so that it will match with the value of 'h1' heading element. 
Need to write a global javascript, which I can use throughout the application for every page.
Kindly advice. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need this?  Are you changing your `h1`s dynamically?  If not, this should really be done on the backend.  And if it is used for SEO purposes, a JS change is usually too late (i.e. the "old" title will be used by search engines).

Comment: Its a project requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.title = $("h1").text();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfectly. How can we take only first <h1> of the page in case there are multiple <h1> in the page?

Comment: No problem. You can select only the first instance of an H1 like this: `document.title = $("h1:first").text();`

Comment: Thanks for a quick response.

Comment: One more query.. I am searching first h1 tag but I wanted to exlude all the <h1> present in class "ui-dialog" from this search. Your help will be really appreciated...

Comment: I think this should work: `document.title = $("h1:not('.ui-dialog h1'):first").text();`

Answer (score 1):

Simply select the correct elements, and assign the text of the `h1` to the text of the `title`:

```
$('title').text($('h1').text());
```

Comment: Thanks David. This also works perfectly. How can we take only first <h1> of the page in case there are multiple <h1> in the page?

Comment: Hi David... One more query.. I am searching first h1 tag but I wanted to exlude all the <h1> present in class "ui-dialog" from this search. Your help will be really appreciated...

Comment: `$('h1').not('.ui-dialog').text()`, assign the text as before. And you will only ever retrieve the text of the first element from the collection, it sets multiple elements' text, it gets only one (the first).